# Ionic + PushWoosh Error Cordova.js not found

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to test pushwoosh with this application
https://github.com/alvaroziqar/ionic-pushwoosh
I did `ionic add platofrm android`
Then `ionic build`

But the notification isn't working. Pushwoosh panel shows 0 android devices. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow the guide correctly:
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap

Please note that for ionic you add pushwoosh plugins as:

```
ionic plugin add pushwoosh-cordova-plugin
```

Also you can try Pushwoosh Ionic sample here:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-cordova-sample/tree/master/Ionic